# How to add css class to input box / radio button on clicking button in angular

Tags: css, angular

I have modal i.e ngx-bootstrap modal in which there are two radio buttons.

**I want to get a shake effect on the selected radio button as validation in case the 'Next' button is clicked.**

I have already created css class for the shake effect. I want to add this css click on clicking on the button when the it is required. I tried using ngClass but it is not working as expected. How this can be done?

HTML

```
<ng-template #myModal>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
                <input formControlName="genderName" type="radio" id="female" value="Female" [ngClass]="{'rederror': this.cf.genderName.required}">
                <label for="female" class="female">Female</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-1 ml-4">
                <input formControlName="genderName" type="radio" id="male" value="Male" [ngClass]="{'rederror': this.cf.genderName.required}">
                <label for="male" class="male">Male</label>
            </div>
            <button type="button" (click)="submit()">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

css file

```
input[type=radio].rederror {
  animation: shake 0.5s 3 linear;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% {margin-left: 0;}
  25% {margin-left: 0.5rem;}
  75% {margin-left: -0.5rem;}
  100% {margin-left: 0;}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 4 (click) changes the class of another element without using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630684/angular-4-click-changes-the-class-of-another-element-without-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can add class in event handler of submit click. sample working code (target whichever element you want class added to instead of .col-md-4) - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j94h2r

```
  submit(): void {
    const eles = this.formContainer.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.col-md-4');
    eles.forEach(ele => ele.classList.add('shake'));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a check to your `ngClass` statement.

As an example you can use the same check as used for a click.

e.g.:

```
<label *ngFor="let radiobutton of radioItems">
  <div>
  <input type="radio" name="options" (click)="model.option = radiobutton"
    [checked]="radiobutton === model.option"
    [ngClass]="{'rederror': radiobutton === model.option}">{{radiobutton}}  
  </div>
</label>
<p>
```

see this working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-buttons-v8recf?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

---

**Edit here comes your complete example:**

html:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
            <input formControlName="genderName" type="radio" id="female" (click)="selectedOption=female" value="female"
                [ngClass]="{'rederror': selectedOption===female && shake}" [checked]="selectedOption===female">
            <label for="female" class="female">Female</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-1 ml-4">
            <input formControlName="genderName" type="radio" id="male" (click)="selectedOption=male"
                [checked]="selectedOption===male" [ngClass]="{'rederror': selectedOption===male && shake}">
            <label for="male" class="male">Male</label>
        </div>
        <button type="button" (click)="submit()">Next</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

components:

```
import { Component,  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  public male = "Male";
  public female = "Female";
  public selectedOption = this.female;
  public shake = false;

  public submit() {
    this.shake = true;    
    setTimeout(() => this.shake = false, 500);
  }
}
```

Together with the working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ballet-animation-3sx8wj?file=app/app.component.ts)!

Comment: I want shaking effect after clicking submit button

Comment: Updated lower example + Stackblitz!

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers too

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do would be to add the styles for the shaking effect to the `:active` pseudoselector.

```css
input:active {
   // css for shaking the radio button
}
```